# Providing gap between two lines where ng-repeat is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am displaying a `div` using `ng-repeat`.
below is the code.

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names track by $index"  style="float:left">
   <span class="facility-label">{{name.fName}}&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

.facility-label {
    background-color: #9e9e9e;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

Once the name reaches to end of div it comes in a new line. But there is no gap in between. How to give that gap between two lines?

Comment: What about using `line-height` property?

Comment: add "display:inline-block" property for class facility-label for last.

Comment: Use css `line-height`.

Comment: here is the solution fiddle using line-height [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ywvw46ox/)

Comment: line-height works for me. :)

Comment: @NarasinghaPadhi So please accept [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43632673/4927984).

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this in css section

```
div {line-height:25px;}
```